# jquery: select element with classname and node index

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a bunch of elements with the class ".myclass". Now I'd like to select one of these elements by its node index and animate it. I get an error that says the element has no function animate.

example:

```
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>

var indizes = [0, 3];

$.each(indizes, function(i, v) {
    $('.myclass')[v].animate({
        left: 100
    }, 1000);
});
```

Apparently the error comes from using a wrong selector. It does work if I use

```
$($('.myclass')[v])
```

instead of

```
$('.myclass')[v]
```

Is this the actual problem? It seems so weird to me to nest selectors.

Comment: `$()` returns a jQuery object. `[0]` gets the DOM node. DOM nodes don't have jQuery methods. Use `.eq()` instead to get a jQuery object for the node at the index.

Comment: :nth-child() Selector might be helpful, although not sure if it is the best choice considering your dynamic index values.

Answer (score 6):

> Is this the actual problem?

Yes. If you access a selected element via bracket notation, you get the raw DOM element back. DOM elements don't have an `animate` method. By passing the DOM element to jQuery again (`$($('.myclass')[v])`) you are creating a jQuery object (again).

You can avoid this and use [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get a jQuery object for the element at that index:

```
$('.myclass').eq(v);
```

It would be better to keep a reference to the selected elements outside the loop though:

```
var indizes = [0, 3];
var $elements = $('.myclass');

$.each(indizes, function(i, v) {
    $elements.eq(v).animate({
        left: 100
    }, 1000);
});
```

Alternatively, you can use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter out the elements you want to animate, which at least looks a bit more concise:

```
$('.myclass').filter(function(i) {
    return $.inArray(i, indizes) > -1;
}).animate({
    left: 100
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything right, and yes you do have to re-wrap the element like so.

```
var indizes = [0, 3],
    elements = $('.myclass');

$.each(indizes, function(i, v) {
    $(elements[v]).animate({
        left: 100
    }, 1000);
});
```

When you do `$('.myclass')[0]` then that element doesn't have any jQuery methods attached to it anymore

Answer (score 0):

when you use `$('.myclass')[v]` you are getting the actual DOM object at index `v`

you could use below instead of trying to use an array notation

```
$('.myclass:eq('+v+')');
```

[:eq doc](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)